# How can i mark a route in google maps by default

Tags: dictionary, default, routes

i have added google map on my website but now i want it to open with an already marked route between point A to B. Also let me know if i can mark the route later on by clicking an external link on the webpage.

This is what im talking about, in case you have any doubts
[image: 2e07.png]
http://imageshack.com/a/img4/4620/2e07.png

This is the code, please modify this code, instead of writing a new code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <style>
    #map_canvas {width: 800px; height: 600px; background-color: #CCC;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
       function initialize() 
    {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.695, 76.855),
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.66843888888889, 76.95485555555555),
    map: map,
    title: 'My Business'
    });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i have the encoded polylines and levels but i need to know, where and how to insert them in my code. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this on my hiking website:

http://www.perry.ch/wp/photos/2013-09-04/track.html

Here I'm using encoded paths, which is a bit complicated to generate, but you can use simple paths like this one:

```
var path = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
```

Comment: hey i acquired the encoded polylines and levels, but i still need to know where and how to put that in my code.